# Pass values from Hidden field to ActionLink then to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to dynamically set the StudentIds by letting the user select check boxes for the reports they want. When they click the ActionLink, I use jQuery to set the values of the ids in a hidden field.   I need the Action Link to read the ids from hidden field.

The values are getting set in the hidden field, but they are not being passed to the controller from the actionLink.

I need to pass the ReportIds to the controller.

```
        @Html.ActionLink("PrintMed", "GetMedEdVerificationReport", "Student", new { studentIdList = Model.ReportIds }, new { @class = "button print_selected print_selectedMedEd disabled" })



        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportIds)
```

javascript

```
$('.print_selectedMedEd').bind('click', function () {
    var ids = getPrintIds();
    if (ids.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $('#ReportIds').val(ids.toString());


    return true;
});
```

Comment: why wouldn't you POST the form values?

Comment: What does your controller action look like? What does the Model look like? What does the rendered HTML look like for the link? When you make the request what does it look like in the debug network monitor?

Comment: sounds like you need to just create a form, put your checkboxes in the form, and just have a submit button.  otherwise your `print_selectedMedEd` needs to update the url in your `PrintMed` link to include the values from `ids` which seems like too much trouble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the asp.net mvc render your `ActionLink` it will generate a link with a parameter that you have on the model. Event you change the value of the model, it will not change the value on the output generated by `ActionLink`.

Given this, you have to se again the value, try to generate an ACtionLink without the argument:

```
@Html.ActionLink("PrintMed", "GetMedEdVerificationReport", "Student", null, new { @class = "button print_selected print_selectedMedEd disabled" })
```

On the javascript side, you could try using the `on` method to bind a event handler and call the `preventDefault` method from the event argument, for sample:

```
$('.print_selectedMedEd').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ids = getPrintIds();
    if (ids.length > 0) {
       $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.ReportIds)').val(ids.toString());

       // make an url to redirect
       var url = $(this).prop("href") + "?studentIdList=" + ids.toString();
       // redirect using the generated url
       window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Remember to use the `Html.IdForm()` to make sure you have the right id for a specific property.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `@Html.ActionLink`doesn't use the hidden fields to make the request. Once the action link renders it becomes
 `<a href="/Student/GetMedEdVerificationReport/reportIds..."> PrintMed </a>`
 so you would need to modify the html on the anchor tag.

You should be using Html.Beginform instead in order to pass along the model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetMedEdVerificationReport", "Student", FormMethod.Post, null))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportIds)
        <input type="submit" value="PrintMed" />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
            <td>

                <input type="button" value="Pickup" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Assignment", new { ID = item.OrderId })'" />
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide some text to explain your answer? While code-only answers can be technically correct, it helps to have some explanation of why the code is the correct solution.